# python logging that uses multiple modules doesn't output the right origin data (filename, funcName...)

Tags: python, logging, multi-module, python-logging

Trying to work with logging and multi modules.

Requirement is to have the a custom log class, that will be able to log event using some method in addition to other methods.

I rather not using a decoration.

logger.py is a common file that will be imported by many other files (modules).

module.py is such a single module for example (see code below).

When running module.py, output is:

2023-05-12 01:17:55,682 DEBUG    -= MSG =- (**logger.py:debug:24**)

some none-logger printing: RPT

Because I ran module.py and not logger.py, I would expect that the first line to be:

2023-05-12 01:17:55,682 DEBUG    -= MSG =- (**module.py:my_func_1:5**)

module.py

```py
from logger import Log, get_module_logger
logger = get_module_logger(__name__)
log = Log(logger)

def my_func_1():
    log.debug("-= MSG =-")
    log.report("RPT")
my_func_1()
```

logger.py

```py
import logging

def get_module_logger(mod_name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(mod_name)
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d)')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    return logger

class Log():
    def __init__(self, logger):
    self.logger = logger

    def report(self, msg):
        print(f"some none-logger printing: {msg}")

    def debug(self, msg):
        self.logger.debug(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping the logger in the `Log` class and calling `self.logger.debug(msg)` in `logger.py`, which means the line on which the `debug()` function is called is in `logger.py`, not `module.py`, hence why `logger.py` is logged as the filename.

Comment: Thanks, can you suggest a fix?